# Pass C# generic type as a parameter

Tags: c#, .net, json, generics

I have an interface declared as

```
public interface ISomething<T> where T : class
```

and somewhere in the interface I have a member declared as

```
[JsonProperty("someProperty")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<List<T>>))]
List<T> SomePropertyList{ get; set; }
```

I get an error on `ConcreteTypeConverter<List<T>>` saying it cannot use a type (T) as an argument. My ConcreteTypeConverter class takes a type T and returns a concrete implementation of T which is needed for JSON deserialization.The scenario here is that T can have about 20 different types.But I would like to avoid having 20 such interfaces - that's why I opted for a generic interface.

Usage would be something like

```
ISomething<SomeType> variable = new Something<SomeType>();
var list = variable.SomePropertyList;
```

where SomeType is the actual implementation of the T. Is there any way to use generics in such a situation?

My ConcreteConverterClass derives from JsonConverter (using Newtonsoft.Json):

```
public class ConcreteTypeConverter<TConcrete> : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, value);
        }

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            return serializer.Deserialize<TConcrete>(reader);
        }
    }
```

My exact error is:

```
Attribute Argument cannot use type parameters
```

Comment: So your question is generic type as an attribute? Can you paste your ConcreteTypeConverter code (just the class def).

Comment: Also the exact error output would be useful.

Comment: Edited the question adding extra info. Yes, basically y question resumes to "Can I send a generic type T as an attribute?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You only need the `ConcreteTypeConverter` if `SomePropertyList` is not a concrete type, e.g.

```
[JsonProperty("someProperty")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<List<T>>))]
IList<T> SomePropertyList{ get; set; }
```

If this is not an issue, just change your property declaration to

```
[JsonProperty("someProperty")]
List<T> SomePropertyList{ get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<List<T>>))]
List<T> SomePropertyList{ get; set; }
```

> I get an error on ConcreteTypeConverter

Since the generic parameters cannot appear in attribute declarations, there is an advice for you from me:

```
public class ConcreteTypeConverter : JsonConverter
```

Removed the `TConcrete`. Since the `ReadJson` returns an object, the power of generics simply fades out.

Second,

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    return serializer.Deserialize<object>(reader);
}
```

Replaced `TConcrete` with an object. If that is not enough for your code to work, try to workaround it. Your method returns an `object` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please apply the attribute on the class implementing the interface.

```
[JsonProperty("someProperty")]
[JsonConverter(typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<List<T>>))]
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was told before, the generic parameters cannot appear in attribute declarations, I encountered the same problem and previous suggestions were not for me, I needed one SingleValueToCollectionConverter which could work like generic. And reflection helped me:

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)   
{
   foreach (var prop in objectType.GetProperties())
   {
      var type = prop.PropertyType;

      if (!type.IsClass)
          continue;

      var destination = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);
      var result = reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray 
            ? serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType) 
            : new List<object> { serializer.Deserialize(reader, type) };

      return Mapper.Map(result, destination, result.GetType(), destination.GetType());
   }

      return null;
 }
```

And using like this (If Data will be Object in json, it will be converted to list):

```
public class BaseResponse<TData>
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleValueToCollectionConverter))]
    public List<TData> Data { get; set; }
}
```

I hope it can help somebody