# How to get type of Class<T> for JsonConverter?

Tags: c#, generics, json.net

I have a class called **Foo**, as shown in the example below. The **Content** property of this class is a ***generic list type***. I want to check if the Content property has one or more items. But I am getting an error as "*an attribute argument cannot use type parameters*". I'm waiting for your help on this. Thanks in advance..

```
[DataContract]
public class Foo<T> where T : class
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrMany<T>))]
    public List<T> Content { get; set; }
}

public class SingleOrMany<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(System.Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

My question is different from the example below. Here T is used in a generic list.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(ConcreteTypeConverter<List<T>>))]
```

Comment: You can't pass generic parameter to attribute.

Comment: Attribute arguments must be compile-time constant(Simple types, string, enums etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pass C# generic type as a parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15520317/pass-c-sharp-generic-type-as-a-parameter)

Comment: As @SeM said you can't use a generic parameter in an attribute; see [Why does C# forbid generic attribute types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/294216).  But is `SingleOrMany<T>` designed to handle the case when the corresponding JSON property could be a single item or an array of items?  If so, try using one of the "universal" non-generic converters from [How to handle both a single item and an array for the same property using JSON.net](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18994685/3744182), for instance `SingleOrArrayListConverter` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53771970/3744182).

Comment: I'm pretty sure `System.Type objectType` in `ReadJson` would represent `List<T>`, so couldn't you exact T from there, rather than passing it via a generic parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Your class doesn't even use `T`. Just remove it. You can obtain type information from the arguments that are passed in (e.g. `objectType`).

Once `T` is removed, you can pass `typeof(SingleOrMany)` to the attribute without issue.

```
[DataContract]
public class Foo<T> where T : class
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(SingleOrMany))]
    public List<T> Content { get; set; }
}

public class SingleOrMany : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(System.Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, System.Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```